# DimensionMismatch: mismatch in dimension

Tags: julia

working on a longblock of code, the sum total of which is [here](https://github.com/mhbw/Discogs-Postman/blob/master/Copy_of_Julia_Colab_Notebook_Template.ipynb). My issue comes in with this particular block:

```
# path_skaters is a string that gives the path to the csv file with the skaters information (see example file for suggested format)
path_skaters = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dscotthunter/Fantasy-Hockey-IP-Code/master/example_skaters.csv"

# path_goalies is a string that gives the path to the csv file with the goalies information (see example file for suggested format)
path_goalies = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dscotthunter/Fantasy-Hockey-IP-Code/673b0a5119ed746a8dc2347206d138c84407def1/example_goalies.csv"


goalies = DataFrame(CSV.File(HTTP.get(path_goalies).body, normalizenames=true, delim=","))

skaters = DataFrame(CSV.File(HTTP.get(path_skaters).body, normalizenames=true, delim=","))


    the_lineup= formulation(skaters, goalies, hcat(zeros(Int, num_skaters + num_goalies), zeros(Int, num_skaters + num_goalies)), num_overlap, num_skaters, num_goalies, centers, wingers, defenders, num_teams, skaters_teams, goalie_opponents, team_lines, num_lines, P1_info)
    the_lineup2 = formulation(skaters, goalies, hcat(the_lineup, zeros(Int, num_skaters + num_goalies)), num_overlap, num_skaters, num_goalies, centers, wingers, defenders, num_teams, skaters_teams, goalie_opponents, team_lines, num_lines, P1_info)
    tracer = hcat(the_lineup, the_lineup2)
    for i=1:(num_lineups-2)
        try
            thelineup=formulation(skaters, goalies, tracer, num_overlap, num_skaters, num_goalies, centers, wingers, defenders, num_teams, skaters_teams, goalie_opponents, team_lines, num_lines, P1_info)
            tracer = hcat(tracer,thelineup)
        catch
            break
        end
    end
```

is producing this error:

```
DimensionMismatch: mismatch in dimension 1 (expected 1 got 190)

Stacktrace:
  [1] _cs
    @ ./abstractarray.jl:1717 [inlined]
  [2] _cshp
    @ ./abstractarray.jl:1713 [inlined]
  [3] _cat_size_shape
    @ ./abstractarray.jl:1693 [inlined]
  [4] cat_size_shape(dims::Tuple{Bool, Bool}, X::Nothing, tail::Vector{Int64})
    @ Base ./abstractarray.jl:1691
  [5] _cat_t(::Val{2}, ::Type{Union{Nothing, Int64}}, ::Nothing, ::Vararg{Any})
    @ Base ./abstractarray.jl:1732
  [6] _cat(::Val{2}, ::Nothing, ::Vararg{Any})
    @ Base ./abstractarray.jl:1728
  [7] #cat#155
    @ ./abstractarray.jl:1916 [inlined]
  [8] hcat
    @ ./abstractarray.jl:1878 [inlined]
  [9] create_lineups(num_lineups::Int64, num_overlap::Int64, path_skaters::String, path_goalies::String, formulation::typeof(one_lineup_Type_4), path_to_output::String)
    @ Main ./In[20]:805
 [10] top-level scope
    @ In[20]:874
 [11] eval
    @ ./boot.jl:368 [inlined]
 [12] include_string(mapexpr::typeof(REPL.softscope), mod::Module, code::String, filename::String)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1428
```

I'm reasonably sure this is because the players data frame and goalies = 190, but I can't figure out why that's a problem.

Comment: The error seems to start at `create_lineups(num_lineups::Int64, num_overlap::Int64, path_skaters::String, path_goalies::String, formulation::typeof(one_lineup_Type_4), path_to_output::String)` which has no `goalies` in it, but does have a String argument called `path_goalies`. Are you passing a dataframe instead of the URL string to path_goalies or something to that effect?

Comment: yes, updated to include that; just to save time, there are 180 rows in the players, 10 in the goalies = 190, hence tracing the error to that

Comment: So could you show the actual code of your function call to create_lineups?

Comment: @Bill good flag, unfortunately stack overflow won't let me post that much code; possible to see it at that link at the top tho. does that work?

Answer (score 1):

The error is saying that you cannot call `tracer = hcat(tracer,thelineup)`:

```
julia> x = zeros(190);

julia> hcat(0, x)
ERROR: DimensionMismatch("mismatch in dimension 1 (expected 1 got 190)")
Stacktrace:
[...]
```

What are you trying to achieve? If you want to concatenate two vectors, you might want `vcat` instead. Or perhaps `pushfirst!.

```
help?> vcat
search: vcat hvcat VecOrMat DenseVecOrMat StridedVecOrMat AbstractVecOrMat VectorConstraint

  vcat(A...)

  Concatenate along dimension 1.

  Examples
  ≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡

  julia> a = [1 2 3 4 5]
  1×5 Matrix{Int64}:
   1  2  3  4  5
  
  julia> b = [6 7 8 9 10; 11 12 13 14 15]
  2×5 Matrix{Int64}:
    6   7   8   9  10
   11  12  13  14  15
  
  julia> vcat(a,b)
  3×5 Matrix{Int64}:
    1   2   3   4   5
    6   7   8   9  10
   11  12  13  14  15
  
  julia> c = ([1 2 3], [4 5 6])
  ([1 2 3], [4 5 6])
  
  julia> vcat(c...)
  2×3 Matrix{Int64}:
   1  2  3
   4  5  6

help?> pushfirst!
search: pushfirst!

  pushfirst!(collection, items...) -> collection

  Insert one or more items at the beginning of collection.

  Examples
  ≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡

  julia> pushfirst!([1, 2, 3, 4], 5, 6)
  6-element Vector{Int64}:
   5
   6
   1
   2
   3
   4
```